# Is there a way to get table/column information from a snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm wondering if there's a way I can access Snowflake to see the column names within a table without actually using the CLI.

e.g. Using a REST API endpoint to return the columns for any/all tables in any format.

Thanks ahead of time.

edit:
My goal is to output something like this to a file :

table1 :
column1,column2,column3...

table2:
column1,column2,column3...

Comment: What's the overall goal? Can you give us more context?

Comment: My goal is to output something like this to a file :

table1 : 
column1,column2,column3...

table2:
column1,column2,column3...

Comment: And you want to use a programing language like Python do so? Would you consider using the Python SDK?

Comment: ... and you don't want to use SQL, right?

Comment: Right, would be great if not SQL? I've begun setting up a JDBC connection in case it cannot be done without using SQL..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for you or not?

```
create or replace table demo
(
  c1 int, 
  c2 text,
  c3 date,
  c4 variant
);

desc table demo;

select 
   'demo' as table_name, 
   ARRAY_AGG("name") as column_names 
from 
  table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
```

You can union such stuff and get the name of all tables and respective columns.

[image]

Comment: How can I get this to work without being in the Web UI or in the CLI?

Comment: When you without WebUI or CLI means? The connector's like python or jdbc don't work for you? What is your primary objective? As far as I know, there is no rest API to invoke SQL. You can write external function and capture them via external function, that could be one work around but it would abuse the feature.

Comment: Was hoping to not need any connectors, but ended up using jdbc to get it done.